# Name of this jQuery feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the name of **jQuery** feature. It is, when you add it, you can slide through your page elements, for example, similar feature is slider (with which you can slide through videos and pictures), but I need to slide through blocks, for example I have 3 small blocks (all content inside div), block size is 600 x 300, I need to add arrows to the side of them, and when I press arrow, it fades away current block and all items inside it, and shows next one.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Are you looking for a [carousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html)?

Comment: Felix, please read first sentence ;)!

Comment: Frédéric, will I be able to scroll with it <div> tags (they are currently 600 x 300 blocks with design)?

Comment: Yah, you can use carousel with any size.

Comment: Okay, I will clarify a little bit, here you can see my website - http://worldofastaria.net/standby/ at center, there is a block, correct? I'm not sure how to call it else lol :), I wan't to scroll it, so if I will be able I'll use Frédéric's solution. Just add answer, so I can choose you as the best answer ;)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is a popular and customizable 'slider' or 'carousel'.  Just google for jquery sliders or jquery carousel, and you will find many other similar 'plugins'.  Many of them have example pages you can look at to see which one you like.  And most of them support sliding 'div' block elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want jQuery functions. try following any one:

```
fadeIn(); fadeOut();
toggle();
slideUp(); slideDown(); slideToggle();
carousel();
```

these are jQuery function. try it.
I hope you will get the solution.

Comment: Hello, could be, maybe you could give me one example with 3 div blocks, how should I control the next and previous buttons?

Comment: http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm 
check this link. you will get example.

Comment: also check the following url :
http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html